# How to remove the volume icon in w7 taskbar

Tags: windows-7

How to remove the volume icon in w7 taskbar. Is it possible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes its possible, right click on your taskbar then click Properties. Under the first tab click the Customize button under 'Notification Area'. Under the scroll box there is a blue link 'Turn system icons on or off' that will give you the option.

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Through Local Group Policy Editor

1. Open the all users, specific users or groups, or all users except administrators Local Group Policy Editor for how you want this policy applied.
2. In the left pane, click/tap on an expand User Configuration, Administrative Templates, and Start Menu and Taskbar.

In the right pane, double click/tap on Remove the volume control icon to edit it.

A) To Disable the Volume Icon - Select (dot) Enabled and click/tap on OK.

B) To Enable the Volume Icon - Select (dot) Disabled or Not Configured and click/tap on OK.